# Countable product of $\mathbb{R}$ is not connected with respect to box topology

Tags: general-topology, connectedness, box-topology

From the book Topology, by James Munkres, I am trying to understand that $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ is not connected with respect to box topology. It is written that,
We can write $\mathbb{R}^\omega$ as the union of the set $A$ consisting of all bounded sequences of real numbers, and the set $B$ of all unbounded sequences. These sets are disjoint, and each is open in the box topology. For if $a$ is a point of $\mathbb{R}^\omega,$ the open set
$$U=(a_1-1,a_1+1)\times (a_2-1,a_2+1)\times...$$
consists entirely of bounded sequences if $a$ is bounded, and of unbounded sequences if $a$ is unbounded....

I do not realise that, how the open set
$$U=(a_1-1,a_1+1)\times (a_2-1,a_2+1)\times...$$ can contain all the bounded sequences of $\mathbb{R}?$ If I choose $a=(1,\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},...) \in \mathbb{R}^\omega,$ then $a$ is a bounded sequence of $\mathbb{R}$. Therefore,
$$U=(1-1,1+1)\times (\frac{1}{2}-1,\frac{1}{2}+1)\times...,$$
which implies that,
$$U=(0,2)\times (-\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{2})\times...,$$
Now, if I consider the bounded sequence $b=(5,5,...)\in \mathbb{R}^\omega,$ then how $b$ can be contained in $U?$
Surely I am missing something, please help me to figure out the concept. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The set $U$ for a particular sequence $a$ will not contain *all* bounded sequences nor all the unbounded sequences either. But, it is a neighborhood of $a$ which is completely contained in one of the two sets of sequences (the bounded sequences or the unbounded sequences). This shows that both sets that make up the separation are open.

Comment: Thank you. Now it's clear.

Comment: @shoteyes Should probably convert that to an answer so the OP can accept it

Comment: @Alan I did something like that earlier today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The set $U$ *only* contains bounded sequences **if** $(a_n)$ is bounded, so is a subset of $A$, and that's all you need because it shows that any bounded sequence is an interior point of $A$. We don't need it to contain *all* bounded sequences: just an open set around $(a_n)$ inside $A$.

The same holds for $B$: **if** $(a_n)$ is unbounded, the defined $U$ also contains only unbounded sequences as well, so $U \subseteq B$ and the sequence is an interior point of $B$.

So $A$ and $B$ only have interior points so both are open, and as $A \cup B = \Bbb R^\omega$, both are closed too, and we have a disconnection.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.

Comment: @user490489 you’re welcome.